# how to append text to checkboxlist item text?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i would like to change the text in my checkboxlist text by appending a text "new". So the new checkboxes are "onenew" and "twonew"?

```
 var resultaat = $("label[for^=CheckBoxList1]").get().split();

            $.each(resultaat, function () {
//how to append 'new' to the values?
            });

 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>one</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>two</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following line instead of `var resultaat ... });`.

```
$("label[for^=CheckBoxList1]").each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text() + "new" );
});
```

Or (as an alternative method):

```
$("label[for^=CheckBoxList1]").text(function(i, text){
    return text + "new";
});
```

Comment: Correct idea, but wrong implementation.. `label` element has no `.val` instead you have to use `.html` or `.text` e.g. `$(this).text( $(this).text() + "new" );` - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YQdaK/).